# Windows10: Installing pyenv-managed python versions under custom path using localadmin-user

Tags: windows, powershell, pyenv

I am working on a Windows10 machine which is restricted by centrally managed guidelines and rules. For example, it is not possible for a normal user to run programs residing in other directories than C:\Program Files... which prevents normal users from installing software on our Windows machines. I do have a *localadmin* user allowing me to run programs residing in other directories and install software. With the help of the *localadmin* user I managed to install pyenv-win following the instructions given at [official PyPi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyenv-win/). As it seems, pyenv is running well, at least I can call pyenv in the PowerShell and it reacts like expected.

Now, I want to install Python versions using pyenv for my normal user (as I do not want to work/program as localadmin). However, if I try `pyenv install <version>` as a normal user, I get an error message that the execution of pyenv-install.vbs is blocked due to group rules. I can install Python versions using the *localadmin*, but the Python installed in this way ends up in the *localadmin's* directory `...\localadmin user directory\.pyenv\pyenv-win\install-chache\python-...exe` which is not accessible for normal users.

Question is, how can I make pyenv Python environments accessible to normal users? One workaround seems to me that I use the *localadmin* user and perform `pyenv install` pointing to some custom directory - e.g. pointing to my normal user's `.pyenv\` directory. Is that possible? What would be the command for this?

Comment: Please talk with your network admin as how to install the apps. Trying to work around company policies is a sure-fire way to get in trouble. That being said, it is possible to exclude your workstation from the said GPO, but that's nw admin's task.

Answer (score 0):

Here I did two thing.
1: Set the PYENV Environment variable for System, I got this in from following link
https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/97
2:Give Everybody full permission to the localadmin folder.

When I installed pyenv as a local temp admin, it got installed in its own folder, probably changing the folder where to install it in the beginning will be helpful. Make sure that folder where pyenv got installed has full rights to everybody.